# JAVA no funciona NOT IN en query PLSQL

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans, plsql

Estoy intentando hacer una condición donde una consulta verifique que los registros no existan en otra tabla y los filtre para despues implementarla en codigo de Java:

```
SELECT
r.*,
e.ent_clave      AS entidad#ent_clave,
e.ent_nombre     AS entidad#ent_nombre,
a.asp_acronimo   AS aspecto#asp_acronimo,
a.asp_nombre     AS aspecto#asp_nombre,
CASE
    WHEN r.req_tipo = 'G' THEN
        n.nor_nombre
    ELSE
        to_char(nov.nov_descripcion)
END AS norma#nor_nombre,
NULL AS pal_cve#pal_cve,
CASE
    WHEN ae.actividadcount > 0 THEN
        1
    ELSE
        0
END AS tieneactividad,
vw.eta_desc      AS req_tipo#eta_desc,
vw2.eta_desc     AS req_tema#eta_desc,
vw3.eta_desc     AS req_autoridad#eta_desc,
vw4.eta_desc     AS req_tip_resolutivo#eta_desc,
vw5.eta_desc     AS req_rep_periodicidad#eta_desc,
vw6.eta_desc     AS req_tip_convenio#eta_desc,
vw7.eta_desc     AS req_tip_estandar#eta_desc,
nov.*,
de.eva_id,
de.dev_considerado,
de.dev_aplica,
de.dev_verificado,
de.dev_cumplido,
de.dev_razon,
de.dev_calificacion
FROM
requisito                                                                                                                                          r
JOIN aspecto                                                                                                                                            a ON a.asp_id = r.asp_id
LEFT JOIN entidad                                                                                                                                            e ON e.ent_id = r.ent_id
LEFT JOIN norma                                                                                                                                              n ON n.nor_id = r.nor_id
LEFT JOIN novedad                                                                                                                                            nov ON nov.nov_id = r.nov_id
JOIN detalle_evaluacion                                                                                                                                 de ON de.eva_id = 687
                              AND de.req_id = r.req_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        r.req_id,
        COUNT(ae.act_id) AS actividadcount
    FROM
        requisito              r
        LEFT JOIN actividad_evaluacion   ae ON ae.eva_id = 687
                                             AND ae.req_id = r.req_id
    GROUP BY
        r.req_id
) ae ON ae.req_id = r.req_id
JOIN vw_multivaluada                                                                                                                                    vw ON vw.lta_nom_tabla = 'REQUISITO'
                           AND vw.lta_nom_campo = 'REQ_TIPO'
                           AND vw.eta_cve = r.req_tipo
JOIN vw_multivaluada                                                                                                                                    vw2 ON vw2.lta_nom_tabla = 'REQUISITO'
                            AND vw2.lta_nom_campo = 'REQ_TEMA'
                            AND vw2.eta_cve = r.req_tema
LEFT JOIN vw_multivaluada                                                                                                                                    vw3 ON vw3.lta_nom_tabla = 'REQUISITO'
                                 AND vw3.lta_nom_campo = 'REQ_AUTORIDAD'
                                 AND vw3.eta_cve = r.req_autoridad
LEFT JOIN vw_multivaluada                                                                                                                                    vw4 ON vw4.lta_nom_tabla = 'REQUISITO'
                                 AND vw4.lta_nom_campo = 'REQ_TIP_RESOLUTIVO'
                                 AND vw4.eta_cve = r.req_tip_resolutivo
LEFT JOIN vw_multivaluada                                                                                                                                    vw5 ON vw5.lta_nom_tabla = 'REQUISITO'
                                 AND vw5.lta_nom_campo = 'REQ_REP_PERIODICIDAD'
                                 AND vw5.eta_cve = r.req_rep_periodicidad
LEFT JOIN vw_multivaluada                                                                                                                                    vw6 ON vw6.lta_nom_tabla = 'REQUISITO'
                                 AND vw6.lta_nom_campo = 'REQ_TIP_CONVENIO'
                                 AND vw6.eta_cve = r.req_tip_convenio
LEFT JOIN vw_multivaluada                                                                                                                                    vw7 ON vw7.lta_nom_tabla = 'REQUISITO'
                                 AND vw7.lta_nom_campo = 'REQ_TIP_ESTANDAR'
                                 AND vw7.eta_cve = r.req_tip_estandar
                                 WHERE
1 = 1
AND r.req_tema = 'M'
AND r.asp_id = 25
AND r.req_id IN (
    SELECT
        de.req_id
    FROM
        detalle_evaluacion   de
        JOIN requisito            r ON r.req_id = de.req_id
    WHERE
        de.eva_id = 687
        AND r.req_status = 'A'
        AND de.dev_considerado = 1
        AND de.dev_aplica = 1
        AND ( NULL IS NULL
              OR de.dev_verificado = NULL )
        AND ( NULL IS NULL
              OR de.dev_cumplido = NULL )
)
AND r.req_id NOT IN (
    SELECT
        pe.req_id
    FROM
        permiso_evaluacion pe
    WHERE
        pe.req_id = r.req_id
        AND pe.res_usu_cve = 'RE000348'
)
ORDER BY
r.req_tipo,
r.req_tema,
r.req_codigo,
to_char(r.req_requisito);
```

La consulta me da los resultados que espero en el SQL Developer, pero al momento de implementarla en el codigo me sigue trayendo todos los resultados y no arroja errores. En Java quedaria asi:

```
ArrayList<Object> parameterList = new ArrayList();
        StringBuffer select = new StringBuffer();
        select.append(" SELECT r.*, e.ent_clave AS entidad#ent_clave, e.ent_nombre AS entidad#ent_nombre, a.asp_acronimo AS aspecto#asp_acronimo, a.asp_nombre AS aspecto#asp_nombre, CASE WHEN r.req_tipo = 'G' THEN n.nor_nombre ELSE TO_CHAR(nov.nov_descripcion) END AS norma#nor_nombre, NULL AS pal_cve#pal_cve");
        select.append(" , CASE WHEN ae.actividadCount > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS tieneActividad");
        select.append(" , vw.eta_desc AS req_tipo#eta_desc");
        select.append(" , vw2.eta_desc AS req_tema#eta_desc");
        select.append(" , vw3.eta_desc AS req_autoridad#eta_desc");
        select.append(" , vw4.eta_desc AS req_tip_resolutivo#eta_desc");
        select.append(" , vw5.eta_desc AS req_rep_periodicidad#eta_desc");
        select.append(" , vw6.eta_desc AS req_tip_convenio#eta_desc");
        select.append(" , vw7.eta_desc AS req_tip_estandar#eta_desc");
        select.append(" , nov.*");
        select.append(" ,de.eva_id, de.dev_considerado, de.dev_aplica, de.dev_verificado, de.dev_cumplido, de.dev_razon, de.dev_calificacion");
        select.append(" FROM requisito r");
        select.append(" JOIN aspecto A ON A.asp_id = r.asp_id");
        select.append(" LEFT JOIN entidad e ON e.ent_id = r.ent_id");
        select.append(" LEFT JOIN norma n ON n.nor_id = r.nor_id");
        select.append(" LEFT JOIN novedad nov ON nov.nov_id = r.nov_id");
        select.append(" JOIN detalle_evaluacion de ON de.eva_id = :eva_id AND de.req_id = r.req_id");
        select.append(" LEFT JOIN (SELECT r.req_id, COUNT(ae.act_id) AS actividadCount FROM requisito r LEFT JOIN actividad_evaluacion ae ON ae.eva_id = :eva_id AND ae.req_id = r.req_id GROUP BY r.req_id) ae ON ae.req_id = r.req_id");

        parameterList.add(evaluacionRow.getEva_id());
        parameterList.add(evaluacionRow.getEva_id());

        select.append(" JOIN vw_multivaluada vw ON vw.lta_nom_tabla = 'REQUISITO' AND vw.lta_nom_campo = 'REQ_TIPO' AND vw.eta_cve = r.req_tipo");
        select.append(" JOIN vw_multivaluada vw2 ON vw2.lta_nom_tabla = 'REQUISITO' AND vw2.lta_nom_campo = 'REQ_TEMA' AND vw2.eta_cve = r.req_tema");
        select.append(" LEFT JOIN vw_multivaluada vw3 ON vw3.lta_nom_tabla = 'REQUISITO' AND vw3.lta_nom_campo = 'REQ_AUTORIDAD' AND vw3.eta_cve = r.req_autoridad");
        select.append(" LEFT JOIN vw_multivaluada vw4 ON vw4.lta_nom_tabla = 'REQUISITO' AND vw4.lta_nom_campo = 'REQ_TIP_RESOLUTIVO' AND vw4.eta_cve = r.req_tip_resolutivo");
        select.append(" LEFT JOIN vw_multivaluada vw5 ON vw5.lta_nom_tabla = 'REQUISITO' AND vw5.lta_nom_campo = 'REQ_REP_PERIODICIDAD' AND vw5.eta_cve = r.req_rep_periodicidad");
        select.append(" LEFT JOIN vw_multivaluada vw6 ON vw6.lta_nom_tabla = 'REQUISITO' AND vw6.lta_nom_campo = 'REQ_TIP_CONVENIO' AND vw6.eta_cve = r.req_tip_convenio");
        select.append(" LEFT JOIN vw_multivaluada vw7 ON vw7.lta_nom_tabla = 'REQUISITO' AND vw7.lta_nom_campo = 'REQ_TIP_ESTANDAR' AND vw7.eta_cve = r.req_tip_estandar");
        select.append(" WHERE 1=1");
        if (requisitoRow != null) 
        {
            
            if (isNotNull(requisitoRow.getReq_tipo())) {
                select.append(" AND r.req_tipo = :req_tipo");
                parameterList.add(requisitoRow.getReq_tipo());
            }
            
            if (isNotNull(requisitoRow.getReq_tema())) {
                select.append(" AND r.req_tema = :req_tema");
                parameterList.add(requisitoRow.getReq_tema());
            }
            if (isNotNull(requisitoRow.getAsp_id())) {
                select.append(" AND r.asp_id = :asp_id");
                parameterList.add(requisitoRow.getAsp_id());
            }
          
            if(isNotNull(requisitoRow.getPal_cve()))
            {
                select.append(" AND ( r.req_requisito like ( '%' || :pal_cve || '%' )  OR  n.nor_nombre like ( '%' || :pal_cve || '%' ))");
                parameterList.add(requisitoRow.getPal_cve());
                parameterList.add(requisitoRow.getPal_cve());
            }
            
            select.append(" AND r.req_id IN(");
            select.append("     SELECT de.req_id ");
            select.append("     FROM detalle_evaluacion de JOIN requisito r ON r.req_id=de.req_id WHERE de.eva_id = :eva_id AND r.req_status=:req_status");
            select.append("     AND de.dev_considerado=1 AND de.dev_aplica=1 AND (:dev_verificado IS NULL OR de.dev_verificado = :dev_verificado) AND (:dev_cumplido IS NULL OR de.dev_cumplido = :dev_cumplido)");
            select.append(" )");
            parameterList.add(evaluacionRow.getEva_id());
            parameterList.add(RequisitoRow.ESTATUS_ACTIVO);
            parameterList.add(evaluacionRow.getFiltro_verificado());
            parameterList.add(evaluacionRow.getFiltro_verificado());
            parameterList.add(evaluacionRow.getFiltro_cumplido());
            parameterList.add(evaluacionRow.getFiltro_cumplido());
            
        }
        select.append("AND r.req_id NOT IN (SELECT pe.req_id FROM permiso_evaluacion pe WHERE pe.req_id = r.req_id AND pe.res_usu_cve = 'RE000348')");
        select.append(" ORDER BY r.req_tipo, r.req_tema, r.req_codigo, TO_CHAR(r.req_requisito)");
```

Copie la consulta que me arroja la variable "select" para copiarla en el Developer y es la misma, solo que al compilar no filtra.

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si guardas el resultado de lo que has ido poniendo en `select` en un archivo de texto (o lo muestras en un control), copias y pegas el texto en SQL Developer?. Puedo predecir que no va a funcionar. Luego, comparas ese texto línea por línea con el que debió haber _producido_ tu rutina en java, cuando identifiques alguna diferencia, regresas al código y ves por qué no produjo lo que tenía que producir y haces algún cambio en el código y ejecutas de nuevo. Si repites ese ciclo las veces necesarias, va a llegar a funcionar.

Comment: El proceso descrito en el comentario anterior se llamaría "depurar tu código" y, en realidad, diría que todo mundo aquí esperaría que tu lo hagas.

Comment: Depurar el código no tenia nada que ver, al parecer la consulta y la porción de código estaba bien, el problema radicaba en una configuración del SQL Developer, aun así gracias por sus respuestas